# Insert rows into temp table where a column has no duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have hundreds of thousands of records with serial numbers.  Many of these are duplicated in other records due to poor record-keeping.

We are doing something now with these records, but we ONLY want records in our new table with unique serial numbers.  SO duplicated rows should be ignores, we will deal with the duplicates later.

(The original table doesn't have a primary key column, either, which is why we are injecting that in our temp table)

```
declare @total int = 603578;
declare @cnt int = 1;

create table #Temp
(
  Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
  FirstName nvarchar(30), 
  LastName nvarchar(30),
  SerialNumber varchar(254),
  ...
)

while @cnt < @total
insert into #Temp SELECT * FROM electronic_list;
```

My hope was to be able to add something simple like:

```
where SerialNumber is unique
```

or

```
where SerialNumber is distinct
```

But it doesn't seem to be that simple.  I have tried different things using select distinct, select count with group by and having, and more, but I can't seem to get the result I am wanting.

There seem to be many ways to *find* duplicates, but hard to find ways to ignore them.

Comment: So, first, we have to work out *what to put in the other columns*. Presumably, the rows that share a serial number aren't identical in other columns (otherwise, you'd not have focussed on that one column, I presume). So what rule should be applied to pick the other column values? Are they going to be some simple aggregate across the values (e.g. `MAX()` or `SUM()`) or are we going to want to pick out *one row* for each serial number? If the latter, what *rule* do we use to select that row?

Comment: We don't want to pick out one serial number if there are dups.  Basically, it could be in the db that one serial number is claimed by two people at two different locations, so we won't want to include them yet at all in anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use *window* function ?

```
select * from (
     select *, 
           count(SerialNumber) over (partition by SerialNumber) Counts 
     from electronic_list
) t
where Counts = @cnt;
```

However, this would select only `SerialNumber` which has only 1 records as your `@cnt` parameter suggests.

Comment: I do want the entirety of each row, though.  Would I need to then take this list of serial numbers and make a second comparison on my way through the original table to see if the current record contains one of these serial numbers?

Comment: @NickEdwards... No, you don't need to use subquery again. Just use `INSERT INTO ...` statement prior to `SELECT...`.

Comment: Did try this but it tells me: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.  The select statement on its own seems to be working fine, though.  But the number of records is about 300,000, which is a little concerning.  I will have to make sure these are non-duplicate in another way, but this code seems sound.  Thank you!

Comment: @NickEdwards... You just need to exclude  `Counts `  columns from `SELECT...` statement or just need to define all possible expression that has same as `INSERT INTO <tbl> (Col1, Col2)`.

Comment: I think it is easier to just add a counts column to the temp table and drop the column later if I need to.  But seems to be working fine otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You can `GROUP` the data and only `INSERT` those rows that have a single item with `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`. Here's some sample code you can run on the follwoing dummy data:

```
serialNumber
-------------
DUPED
DUPED
UNIQUE
DISTINCT
ANOTHERDUPE
ANOTHERDUPE
ANOTHER_UNIQUE
```

The full example:

```
CREATE TABLE #serials
    (
        id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
        serialNumber NVARCHAR(254)
    );

CREATE TABLE #electronic_list
    (
        serialNumber NVARCHAR(254)
    );

INSERT INTO #electronic_list ( serialNumber )
VALUES ( N'DUPED' ) ,
       ( N'DUPED' ) ,
       ( N'UNIQUE' ) ,
       ( N'DISTINCT' ) ,
       ( N'ANOTHERDUPE' ) ,
       ( N'ANOTHERDUPE' ) ,
       ( N'ANOTHER_UNIQUE' );

-- SELECT *
-- FROM   #electronic_list AS el;

INSERT INTO #serials ( serialNumber )
            SELECT   serialNumber
            FROM     #electronic_list AS el
            GROUP BY el.serialNumber
            HAVING   COUNT(el.serialNumber) = 1;

SELECT *
FROM   #serials AS s;

DROP TABLE #electronic_list;
DROP TABLE #serials;
```

Produces:

```
id          serialNumber
----------- ---------------
1           ANOTHER_UNIQUE
2           DISTINCT
3           UNIQUE
```

You just need to extend the code to insert data from the other columns.

Comment: By extending the code here, do you mean doing a select column1, column2, etc. goruping by serialNumber having count of serialnumber = 1?  That wouldn't work though, would it?  Hmm...  I'll give it a try in a few.  Thank you.

Comment: That comment assumes that the values in the other rows would not make rows with duplicate serial numbers also unique. For example, suppose you have two `DUPED` rows, with different values in their other fields. Grouping on all fields would then make those rows distinct and they would be inserted. Instead you could use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT el.SerialNumber) = 1`, or aggregate the values in the other fields using, e.g. `MAX`, which would be fine when there's only a single matching row.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT el.SerialNumber) = 1` will not give the output as you mentioned but if we don't use `DISTINCT` then it will be.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is `CTE` though its already done using the `subquery` so just trying to show the more alternatives, which may be efficient

```
WITH ignoreDuplicate AS (
     SELECT SerialNumber, 
           COUNT(SerialNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber) tot 
     FROM electronic_list
)
SELECT SerialNumber FROM ignoreDuplicate WHERE tot = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although window functions are a simple way to do this, probably the most efficient is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from #test t
where not exists (select 1 from #test t2 where t2.SerialNumber = t.SerialNumber and t2.id <> t.id);
```

For performance, you want an index on `#test(SerialNumber, id)`.

This is faster because basically you are scanning `#test1` and simply looking up a value in an index -- which is quite fast.  It is hard to think of a faster potential execution plan.